# What link is this link?

Tags: knot-theory

I am trying to identify the following link

[image]

SnapPy is not able to identify it.

Please let me know if you have the answer.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The census on SnapPy only has knots and links identified up to 16 crossings I believe, so since your link has 22 crossings, there is no chance of an identification.  But it is not hard to see that this is a [satellite link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot) of the Whitehead link ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link), [Knot Atlas](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/L5a1), [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WhiteheadLink.html)). Image below is from Knotatlas.

[image: A pink circle with an sideways figure-8 laying over it, and alternating.]

The standard Whitehead link looks like a circle with a figure 8 overlaid, then made alternating.  The circle component, we can see was replaced with the unlink on two components with $0$-framing (i.e. no twisting) and the figure 8 was also replaced with two components but we have some twisting going on.  If you want to be precise, you will need to work out the framing on the figure 8 part.  Framing is not obvious, so I would avoid just eyeballing it.  See [Rolfsen](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/rolfsen.pdf) for some in-depth discussion of framings. Page 110 I think is where it starts.

Good luck.